# Checkmark won't show in TableViewCell on iOS7

Tags: ios6, uitableview, ios7

I'm working on a weird issue right now. My Apps Deployment Target is set to iOS6, so I want to support both iOS6 and iOS7.

I just have a simple UITableView, in which the user can select the preferred notification sound.

The code for `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` is:

```m
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CheckmarkCell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        [cell setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        if (indexPath.section == 0){
            cell.textLabel.text = [_availableSounds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            if (indexPath.row == _checkedSoundIndexPath.row) {
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            }
        }
        else {
// Unrelated, another settings cell
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
                cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
            }
            return cell;
        }
```

My `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` looks like the following:

```m
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section != 0) {
        return;
    }
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    [[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
    if (_checkedSoundIndexPath != indexPath) {
        [[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:_checkedSoundIndexPath] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
    }
    _checkedSoundIndexPath = indexPath;
}
```

The problem is that an iOS7 iPhone won't show the checkmark as expected. Running the same code on an iOS6 iPhone works as expected. I tried to insert `[cell setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];` but without any luck. Even if I remove all AccessoryType related code and add the checkmark in my storyboard nothing appears. See screenshots below (first is iOS6 and second is iOS5).

Does anyone have an idea ? Or is it a bug in iOS7 ?

Thanks in advance !

**Edit:**

Even if I make a new simple UITableViewController, with just 5 cells with the Accessory set to UITableViewAccessoryTypeCheckmark, the Checkmarks won't appear on iOS7.

[image: iOS6 on an iPhone 4]
[image: iOS7 on an iPhone 5]

Comment: Another note. UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark and UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator won't show up anywhere in my app. UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton and UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailButton work as expected.

Comment: So happy, that I'm not the only one facing this problem. :-)

Comment: Is there a custom subclass of UITableViewCell? (You can see this in Interface Builder)

Comment: No, it's a UITableViewCell with basic style.

Comment: I'm having the same problem: project developed originally for iOS 5, checkmarks and disclosure indicators invisible only on iOS 7, although detail disclosure button and detail button work fine. I've tried the fixes suggested so far, with no luck. Audience, did you ever find a solution? (I can always use the accessory view to display my own checkmark and disclosure images, but that seems like a nasty hack.)

Comment: I've ended up implementing the hack you mentioned. I've made an image of the checkmark. This image is used as the accessory view. Incredible bad way, but it works. Will try to get in touch with Apple about this.

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar problem and I solved this issues changing the tint color of the uitableview

I changed the tintcolot of uitable by InterfaceBuilder to Default color

or

```
tableView.tintColor =  [UIColor blackColor];
```

Comment: Not for me. :-( Still no luck with tableView.tinitColor and cell.tintColor. Accessory won't appear. Is it working in your app, giuseppe?

Comment: Correct. Basically the tableView.tintColor property needs to set to any color but the "default" in the storyboard or nib. I've set it to blue and have no problems now.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! I created a UITableView programmatically and the UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark was always white. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same problem as you are for a long time.
In my case I implemented some appearance tweaks. And one of them was

```m
[[UIView appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Try to find in your project global things like that.

Answer (score 2):

```
In my application it working perfect,check it
```

```m
//take it in .h file mutable arSelectedRows;
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   if (cell == nil) {
       cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
   [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray];

   //Do anything you want for cell here
   if([arSelectedRows containsObject:indexPath]) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
   else {
          cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
   return cell;
}

 #pragma mark - Table view delegate

 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
   if(cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
       cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
       [arSelectedRows addObject:indexPath];
   }
   else {
      cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
       [arSelectedRows removeObject:indexPath];
  }
   NSLog(@"id are here :%@",arSelectedIDs);

   [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

}
```

may be ,it will helpful.

Comment: Basically the same logic then my code. Tried to make a new UITableViewController class with your code, but still no luck with the checkmark. UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark and UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator won't show up throughout my app. But thanks anyway.

Comment: This resolution is pretty close to my answer but missing one important thing. Also, I would have done the required correction here but I don't recommend using cellForRowAtIndexPath: method call inside other methods to get data. Check out my answer and feel free to comment there.

Answer (score 0):

No, There is No Problem with **UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark** in iOS 7,Make sure you have implemented correct logic for it.

Comment: It's working on iOS6, so I think the logic is correct. Maybe you can help to find the error in my code.

Comment: i have checked tableview with UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark and it show perfect. if you want to try create simple app with ios7 with a tableview and set there accessoryType to UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark.

Comment: If I make a new project everything works fine. That's some sort of weird. But I can't rewrite the project from scratch.

Comment: I've added a note to the question. I've also tried to make a new class, but the checkmarks won't appear.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your checksoundIndexpath, please check whether it has a correct indexpath, Or First check with hardcoded indexpath.

you are not initializing the checksoundindxpath.

Also I noticed you are not assigning the selected row indexpath to _checkSoundIndexpath, Only you are checking if both indexpaths(current indexpaths and _checksoundindexpath) are equal, But if they are different then you should assign the selected indedxpath to _checksound indexpath.

Comment: I initialize the variable in the view controllers `-init`. Even if I hardcode it like `_checkedSoundIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0];` the checkmark won't appear. I missed the one line in my `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`, when copying the code. Thanks for the answer anyway.

Comment: Ok I am not sure, but try [cell bringSubViewToFront:cell.accessoryView] in willDisplaycell: atIndexpath: method

Answer (score 0):

I would rather reload tableview (preferably only the affected rows - using `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths`) after settings appropriate data in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method.

```m
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// Other logic..

            [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO]; // Would like to look for an alternative method to avoid this refresh??

            NSMutableArray *reloadArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:2];
            [reloadArray addObject:indexPath];

            [reloadArray addObject:_checkedSoundIndexPath];

            self.checkedSoundIndexPath = indexPath;   // Should set this before reload
            [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:reloadArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}
```

And, most importantly, add these lines in cellForRowAtIndexPath: method -

```m
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // All your other code for this section followed by these lines...

    if([_checkedSoundIndexPath compare:indexPath] == NSOrderedSame) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    // Other sections code
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint with comparing index pathes and reloading the affected cells, but still no luck with the checkmark. Ridiculous, it won't show up.

Answer (score 0):

I can solve this problem by set tint color for Cell
It didnt show because cell tint in white ,and cell selectionstyle is none

```m
cell.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    if(cell.selected){
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
    }else{
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the original question uses a simple `UITableViewCell` but this might work for someone else with a custom table view cell.

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass. I tried everything but the checkmark won't show. Eventually I realised that I overrode `layoutSubviews` but forgot to call `[super layoutSubviews]`. Which meant the checkmark would not show correctly.

```
 - (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    //...custom layout here
}
```