# UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark not showing in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I'm having a problem showing the Checkmark accessory in my cell.
When I use something another type of accessory it works but not with the Checkmark accessory.

It works perfectly in iOS 6 but not on iOS 7.
When am I missing?

```
 (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:EVENT_SELECTION_CELL_IDENTIFIER forIndexPath:indexPath];
    Event *event = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = event.name;
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    if ([event.current boolValue]) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: They changed the defaults in ios7. :)

The cell has a default background color when selected. In iOS 7, the selection color is no longer blue. Use *UITableViewCellSelectionStyleDefault* instead.

    float version = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
    if (version >= 7.0)
        {
          cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleDefault;
        }
    else{
       cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

Comment: I have the same problem. See my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19249389/checkmark-wont-show-in-tableviewcell-on-ios7/19418537

Answer (score 23):

I solved this issues changing the tint color of the uitableview

I changed the tintcolot of uitable by InterfaceBuilder to Default color

or

```
TableView.tintColor =  [UIColor blackColor];
```

Answer (score 3):

In case this might help somebody.... for me, setting the tableview tint color did not work, but setting the cell tint color in cellForRowAtIndexPath did work:

```
cell.tintColor = [UIColor grayColor];
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the blue checkmark back (similar to iOS6), you can use:

```
cell.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(0.0/255.0) green:(122.0/255.0) blue:(255.0/255.0) alpha:1.0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as a reality check since your code seems ok
can you change your [event.current boolValue] to YES , it seems the issue is actually in the value...
I will also check the delegate of the tableview..

if not this or that, let us know... i will delete this answer...

```
if (YES) {
//..
}
```

Comment: I have already tried things like that but that didn't change anything. When I use another accessorytype it works